# Como recibir datos de php a ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, poo

Estoy practicando POO de PHP con javascript y ajax, tengo mi codigo listo con la consulta sql:

```
public function SessionStart() {

        $conexion = $this->conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND pass = ?";

        $consulta_preparada = $conexion->prepare($sql);

        $consulta_preparada->execute(array($this->nombre, $this->pass));

        //rowCount devuelve el numero de filas con las que ha coincidido, 1 o 0

        $login = $consulta_preparada->rowCount();


        if ($login > 0) {

            session_start();

            $datos = new stdClass();

            $datos->usuario = "Shum";
            $datos->edad = "18";

            $this->json= json_encode($datos);

        }else {

            $this->json = 0;
        }
    }
```

json es una variable global, y si la consulta tiene exito creo un array guardando los datos en el y luego en la variable json.

Este se devuelve mediante el metodo getJson:

```
public function getJson() {

        return $this->json;
    }
```

aqui mi codigo JS:

```
$("#php").submit(function () {

    //empaquetamos las variables

    usuario = $(".usuario").val();
    pass = $(".pass").val();

    if (usuario === "" || pass === " ") {

        alert("Datos incorrectos");

    }else {

        var usuario_pass = {

            usuario:$(".usuario").val(),
            pass:$(".pass").val()
        }

        //los pasamos por post a la pagina

        $.post("Login_variables.php", usuario_pass, login);

    }

    //con esto la pagina no se actualiza al presionar submit
    return false;
});

function login (json) {

    var jSON = $.parseJSON(json);

    if (jSON.usuario != 0) {

        $("#acceso").innerHTML = " ";
        $("#acceso").text("Acceso permitido");

        alert;

    }else {

        $("#acceso").innerHTML = " ";
        $("#acceso").text("Acceso denegado");
    }
}
```

como pueden ver en la parte de ajax, le paso las variables a la pagina Login_varibles.php, en la que les dejare el codigo:

```
<?php

require ("Conexion.php");
require ("Login.php");

$login = new login();

$login->SessionStart();

echo $json = $login->getJson();
```

?>

todo listo, creo una nueva instancia el cual se hara cargo de la sentencia y una vez terminada llamo al metodo getJson para que me devuelva el Json, pero a la hora de acceder a los valores desde php, me sale undefined, asi lo hago: 
`function login (json) {

```
    if (jSON.usuario != 0) {

        $("#acceso").innerHTML = " ";
        $("#acceso").text("Acceso permitido");
        alert(jSON.usuario);

    }else {

        $("#acceso").innerHTML = " ";
        $("#acceso").text("Acceso denegado");
    }
}
```

no se por que, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradeceria :)

Comment: ¿Has verificado cómo se están recibiendo los datos en la función `login`, mediante un `console.log(json);`? Más adelante conviene que te replantees ciertos criterios, como el hecho de usar una variable global combinándola con POO... eso tiene poco sentido, lo más lógico sería declarar esa variable como un miembro de la clase y poder acceder a ella desde un método de la misma. En POO uno de los conceptos básicos es la *encapsulación*. Una variable global rompe totalmente ese concepto.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo otra manera de implementarlo con `ajax`, espero y te sirva y se lo puedas implementar a tu proyecto, te comentaré el código para que tengas una idea de cómo lo hace, ejemplo:

```
$this->json= json_encode($datos);//En lugar de esto
echo json_encode($datos);//cambialo por esto
/*
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
*/

$('#btnEnviar').click(function(){//Puedes uarlo como submit o click, como se te haga mejor

    var v_usuario = $(".usuario").val();
    var v_pass = $(".pass").val();

    if(v_usuario != "" && v_pass != ""){

         $.ajax({
         url: 'Login_variables.php',//El archivo .php que recibirá los parámetros, pon bien la ruta.
         type: 'GET',//El método para obtener los datos
         dataType: 'json',//Le dices que recibirás como respuesta un json
         data: {usuario: v_usuario, pass: v_pass},//le mandas los parámetros
         }).done(function(data){//El data recibirá el json_encode

         /*Depende de lo que le asignes despues de '$datos->', es lo que recibirá el data 
           $datos->usuario = "Shum";
           $datos->edad = "18";
         */
         if(data.usuario != "" && data.edad != ""){
          //si lo que te devuelva la consulta en el data son diferentes de vacío, quiere decir que sí encontró al usuario. 
           alert('Acceso correcto');
         }else{
           alert('Acceso incorrecto');
         }

        });
    }       
 });
```